# Entity Framework Context Not Working

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out Entity Framework but I keep running into issues with the context. I create my .edmx file and it works fine but when I try to declare my context on my pages Visual Studio will not find them. My .edmx file is called YCLModel.edmx and my connectionstring for it is YCLEntites.

I try to declare the context as:

```
Dim yclcontext as new YCLEntites
```

I have also tried going into design mode and dragging  from the toolbox but when I select my named connection it gives me the following error:

> The metadata specified in the connection string could not be loaded.
>   Consider rebuilding the web project to build assemblies that may
>   contain metadata. The following error(s) occurred:
>
> Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `edmx` file was in the `app_data` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your .edmx file defined in a separate project other than your web project? If so, you should copy the connection string data from the `app.config` of your project to your web project.

Comment: I created the .edmx file in the App_Code folder of the project. The connection string is also already in the web.config.

Comment: I figured it out. It appears that you cannot place the .edmx file into an "App_Data" folder.